# How can I insert text at every number in a string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I have a list of strings like 'C5B2GH5' and I want to add a '{\sub [num]}' for every number. I can't think of any way to keep the numbers in the string. So it would go from 'G2H3' to 'G{\sub 2}H{\sub 3}'. Is there any relatively simple way to do this? My biggest problem is keeping the number in the string.

Comment: What is your definition of 'num'?  The answer is very different if num is a single character vs. multiple characters vs. a floating point number written as text.  In general, `isdigit(c)` will be your friend

Comment: [num] is just a placeholder for the digit that will go there. Now that I think about it, I want to be able to recognize any length series of digits. Something like 'C145' should turn into 'C{\sub 145}'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this?:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'(\d+)','{\sub \\1}','C5B2GH5')
#output: C{\sub 5}B{\sub 2}GH{\sub 5}
```

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. Mind explaining how it works exactly?

Comment: Regular expressions. `\d+` pattern looks for any digit (one or more) and the method replaces with what it just matched (which is `\1`). Know about regular expressione here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression. And the python module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html